# Remove service from nagios console though chef

Tags: chef-infra, nagios, chef-recipe

I am removing nrpe check by running a chef recipe for dynamodbmonitor.

```
nrpe_check "check_dynamodbmonitor" do
command "#{node['nrpe']['plugin_dir']}/check_procs"
parameters '-a dynamic-dynamodb -c 1:15'
action :remove
end
```

nrpe_check is getting removed but the service is not getting removed from nagios console giving a critical alert saying nrpe_check is not defined. Any thoughts on how to remove the service from console.

Comment: Look at how that custom resource is implemented and compare to whatever commands you would normally run by hand. If needed, fix the cookbook.

Comment: I have tried deleted the cfg files and monitoring services from commands.cfg file, it worked in removing the monitoring from console, but in the next chef-client run, it keeps adding it back.